# JSF dataTable with selectOneListbox

Tags: jsf, datatable

I have a dataTable that lists some objects and I want to set a property for those objects using a selectOneListbox. This is my dataTable

```
<h:dataTable value="#{someHandler.entities}"
                binding="#{someHandler.dataTable}" var="entitiy">
               <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <t:outputText value="Level" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:selectOneListbox id="level" value="#{entitiy.level}" size="1"
                        valueChangeListener="#{someHandler.changeLevel}"
                        onchange="submit()">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="-" itemLabel="-" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="ALL" itemLabel="ALL" />
                        (and so on)
                    </h:selectOneListbox>
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <t:outputText value="Name" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{entitiy.name}" />
                </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

The valueChangeListener looks like this:

```
public void changeLevel(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    String newLevel = (String) event.getNewValue();
    Logger logger = (Logger) dataTable.getRowData();        
    logger.setLevel(Level.toLevel(newLevel));
}
```

(dataTable is an HtmlDataTable object.)

However, the event object is always the same - no matter which row the selectOneListbox was in. (It seems always the logger in the first row). The Logger object I get is also not the one I want.

Any ideas? Thank you!

And anothers questions? Is the entitiy.setLevel() method called even though I have a valueChangeListener? I use entitiy.level because I want to show the chosen level as a default for those entity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two potential problems here:

---

First, the `onchange="submit()"` submits the **entire** form. The `valueChangeListener` will be invoked on **all** input elements of which the *submitted* value differs from the *initial* value.

You need to preset the value behind `#{entitiy.level}` with the same value as the default menu option. E.g. in the constructor.

```
public Entity() {
    level = "-";
}
```

Or, better, make the default value `null`.

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-" />
```

so that the `valueChangeListener` won't be invoked when the particular menu is not changed.

Or, when you are already on JSF 2.x (please always mention exact JSF impl/version in your JSF questions), you can use `<f:ajax>` tag for this without the need for a `valueChangeListener` with a hacky `onchange="submit()"`.

---

Second, you need to ensure that the datatable value `#{someHandler.entities}` returns **exactly** the same list during the submit as it was during the initial request. So, do the data loading in the bean (post)constructor. In JSF 2.x you'd like to put the bean in the view scope as well.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you can also just use `<h:selectOneMenu>` instead of a `<h:selectOneListbox size="1">`.

Comment: Thank you very much BalusC, I have learned a lot from you already! But there is a problem: Actually I would like to have the entity.level preset with a value I get by calling some third party class. Every row should show the current level (that's why I don't want to display "-" in every row) and if I change the value of that listbox, the level should change (for only that row). I'll see what I can do using ajax.